# BackgroundWorker not updating GUI at other Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, backgroundworker

As stated I have a BackgroundWorker that runs a sub function DoHeavyWork().

```vb
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            'DO HEAVY WORK
            DoHeavyWork()
        End If
    End Sub
```

```vb
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        Label8.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %"
    End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Label8.Text = ""
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Completed!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Inside this sub function DoHeavyWork(), there are codes to update another form's GUI.

```vb
Private Sub DoHeavyWork()
For i As Integer = 1 To fresult_counter
  Dim fresult As New Button
                fresult.Name = "fresult_" & i
                fresult.Text = result(index_acc(i - 1)).ToString

                fresult.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                fresult.Width = 265
                fresult.AutoSize = True
                fresult.BackColor = Color.White

                With fresult.FlatAppearance
                    .BorderColor = Color.White
                    .BorderSize = 2
                    .MouseDownBackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
                    .MouseOverBackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
                End With
                fresult.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left
                fresult.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
                fresult.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
                fresult.Location = New Point(0, 22 * (i - 1))
                Form1.TabControl2.TabPages(1).Controls.Add(fresult)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
 Next
 End Sub
```

The problem is it did not update the GUI but the progress bar is working. I've tried getting the set of code out of the BackgroundWorker and it works fine. Is there something I did not set to enable BackgroundWorker to update the GUI?

Comment: It's because those are on a different thread. The progress bar works because it's not on the UI thread, the others probably are... Look into delegates and invoking, you'll find what you need. Also your leaving out the main code in question, what is in `DoHeavyWork` as it is probably trying to change controls...

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will look into it.

Comment: You clearly have done very little research on using a `BackgroundWorker`. The whole point is to do BACKGROUND work. Anything to do with the UI is the exact opposite of background work. In your case, everything you're doing involves the UI so you CANNOT us a `BackgroundWorker` at all.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am so sorry, I did not completely finish listing the DoHeavyWork sub function, it still has the progress bar. I've updated it. Like you said, I am indeed not familiar with BackgroundWorker.

Comment: As I said, UI = foreground.  You simply cannot use a `BackgroundWorker` to do what you are trying to do.  It's for things like calculations, data retrieval file processing, etc, NOT building a UI.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you so much! Understood what you said and got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney), the solution for my answer is very simple.

Just let the BackgroundWorker update the progress bar at the background. And when it finished doing it's work, the progress bar will be at 100 which means it is completed.

Once it is completed, simply add the update GUI codings (in my case: 'Form1.TabControl2.TabPages(1).Controls.Add(fresult)') at the sub function when BackgroundWorker has completed:

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Label8.Text = ""
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Completed!")
            Form1.TabControl2.TabPages(1).Controls.Add(fresult)
        End If
    End Sub
```